# Html5 Video. After 20 secs of pause reset player

Tags: html5-video, reset, onpause

So im working on a school project for a museum, we are making an info screen with a video to play for the visitors, ill like to make a function so that if one visitor is pausing the video and leave it will reset after 20 sec or so. So the next visitor dont have to reset the video by him self.

Any easy way to do that?

I just use the standard html5 video player and controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help on a danish forum
a guy made an example i could modify for my own project it worked for me
the solution:

http://netkoder.dk/test/test0221.html

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos
it might help 
probably you need to write your required code within

```
  if (video.paused == true)
    {

    //find out code to find whether its been paused for 20 second.....may be use some timer control to get this 

    if(20secPaused) 
    {
     video.currentTime = time;
    }
```

hope it helps :)